# laurent series expansion problem 1

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the laurent series for the function $\frac{1}{z+z^2}$ for domain $0<|z+1|<1$.

I separated the function into:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{z+1}$

I am having trouble with the second term. What I tried to do was $\frac{1}{z+1}=\frac{1}{z+1}*\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{z+1}}$ but obviously they not equal any hinto as to how to start will be appreciated and thanks!

Comment: You want the series to have the form $\sum_{n\in \mathbb {Z}}a_n(z+1)^n.$ So the second term is fine. It's the first term you want to rewrite.

Comment: Then $\frac{1}{z}=\sum(z+1)$ and then $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+1}\sum(z+1)^j$ and then done?!

Comment: everything multilpied by a minus

Answer (score 2):

$$f(z) = \frac1{z+1} \frac1{z+1-1} = -\frac1{z+1} \frac1{1-(z+1) }=-\frac1{z+1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (z+1)^k$$